# Multiple pages that appear only once at the beginning of the report

Tags: jasper-reports

The first 2 pages of the report are static and I am using `Title Band` for them.

The height of the `Title Band` is 796 px. And each of the 2 pages uses the whole area.

So I made a layout for the 1st page, insirted a page break and now want to extend the height of `Title Band` for the 2nd page layout. But JR Studio does not allow this to me.

Is there a way to have a printed height of the title = 796 px (based on page format properties) but with page breaks allow to extend the height of the Title Band for several pages (only in JR Studio) and have, for instance, title height of 796*2 px?

Answer (score 0):

The main motiviation of this issue, is not using Title, but trying to find a solution, when a report has some pages at the beginning, that appear only once and use the whole page area.

Trying to use Title band for this purpose is limited with its height, as mentioned in the issue description.

Possible solutions:

- Using subreports. Actually I've seen this option as a recommended one. The issue: structer and report template become more complicated, you have to have subreports in a compiled form.
- Using Detail Band for the first pages that must appear only once with `printWhenExpression` based on `$V{PAGE_NUMBER}` variable together with a Page Break element to start a new Detail Band on the new page.

I used the last option. [JR template example](https://github.com/AlexandrSokolov/jasper_reports/blob/master/src/main/resources/jr/template.sections.jrxml)